# Upper bound for sum of exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions, karamata-inequality

I want to show that for any vector $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i = 0$ and $m=\textrm{max}_i |a_i|$, it holds  $$\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n e^{a_i} \leq \cosh (m)\, .$$ I really appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ is even and $\max\limits_{i}a_i=m$.

Since $e^x$ is a convex function, by Karamata we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^ne^{a_i}\leq\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n}{2}e^{-m}+\frac{n}{2}e^m\right)=\frac{e^m+e^{-m}}{2}=\cosh{m}.$$
The case $n$ is odd for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, i did not know Karamata's inequality and needed a moment to understand what majorization means.

Comment: @Philmore I am ready to explain. By the way, I think it's better to wright $\max\limits_{i}|a_i|=m$. I am ready to fix my post if you want.

Comment: @Michael_Rozenberg Your post is great. Obviously one does not have to look at two different cases by looking at the double-sized vector with two copies of every element of $a$. I would have had a really hard time proving above inequality without your suggestion of using Karamata.